# simple ajax call to database to verify email php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On blur of an e-mail textbox, I want it to do an ajax call back and verify if the e-mail is already in use.

The call is finding the webmethod, however, it's returning a null value.  I trimmed the code and I'm getting a null value with the following:

```
function chkEmail(email) {
    var prom = $.Deferred();

    console.log(email);
    $('#emailCheckGIF').show();
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'emailAvailable',
        data: { 'email': email },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data + ' good');
            prom.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown + ' error');
            prom.reject(errorThrown);
        }
    });

    return prom;
}
```

My simplified web method

```
    public function emailAvailable($email = null) {


        echo json_encode($email);
    }
```

In the firefox dev tools, it says the email param is being passed correctly and the response from the service is NULL

If I remove the `json_encode` it comes over as a blank string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try This --

My Controller --

```
  public function checkEmail()
      {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $result = $this->federation_model->checkEmail($email);
        echo json_encode($result);
      }
```

My Model --

```
public function checkEmail($email)
        {
            $this->db->where('user_email', $email);
            $result=$this->db->get('users')->row_array();
            if(is_array($result))
                {

                    return $result;
                }   
            else
                {
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

My View --

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<input name="assoc_email" id="assoc_email" type="email" class="form-control"/>
<span id="line2" class="text-left"></span>
</div>
```

My Script --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#assoc_email').keyup(function(){
            var email = $('#assoc_email').val();
            var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; 
// my ajax function will call after enter the valid email
            if(email == "" ||  !filter.test(email))
                {
                    $('#line2').html("");
                    $('#submit_assoc').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            if(filter.test(email) && email != "")
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>federation/checkEmail",
                    type:"post",
                    data:"email="+email,                    
                    success: function(data){
                        var result = JSON.parse(data);
                        if(result == "")
                            {
                                $('#line2').html("<?php echo $this->lang->line('email'); ?>  <?php echo $this->lang->line('available'); ?> ");
                                $('#line2').css('color', 'green');
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $('#line2').html("<?php echo $this->lang->line('email'); ?>  <?php echo $this->lang->line('already'); ?> <?php echo $this->lang->line('exists'); ?>");
                                $('#line2').css('color', '#f3565d');
                            }

                    }
                    });
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```